# What's the simplest and most robust way to have constant-height submit button with rounded corners?

Tags: css

Constant height so just left/right images should be necessary instead of having 4+, right? I'd still want top-to-bottom color gradient (and different one on hover).

If possible, I'd prefer if it was still an `<input type='submit'>` and not anything weird.

Is there any way (website / imagemagick script etc.) to generate these images automatically or do I need to draw them in some graphics program?

Comment: You could always do it Google's way and nest approximately 13 trillion divs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a site that will let you create them: http://www.iwebtoolsonline.com/html-and-css-rounded-corner-button-generator

Comment: Cool tool.  Bookmarking that for later use.  Hate to be a spoilsport, though, but it seems to create a funny jagged edge in Chrome.

Comment: Works for me in Chrome (Mac). Could you provide details of your problem?